# Custom section titles do not look similar (despite having the same code)

Tags: titlesec, section-titles

I produce the following custom section titles:

[image]

There is quite a bit of stuff that is hardcoded (i.e. requires me to eyeball it) in here, which makes me nervous.

1. Why are the two `vrules` not the same width (they both have `3pt` thickness)? This problem goes away if I change `\titlespacing\section{6.8in}{0in}{0in}` to `\titlespacing\section{6.0in}{0in}{0in}`, but I don't know why it's happening.
2. How do I ensure that the right-aligned title is flush to the margin? Now, it's manually done using the `6.67in` value (width of a4 paper - width of left margin - width of right margin = 8.27 - 0.8 - 0.8 = 6.67), but for some reason, the space on the right looks bigger than on the left.
3. How do I ensure a similar space between the `vrule` and text for both? Now, it's manually done using `\hspace` and I am sure they are not the same.

I really appreciate all input - doing things manually makes me very antsy.

---

MEW for above:

```
% these define the type of document and the look of the page
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, top = 1.3in, headheight = 0.6in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[bottom, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip} % space between footnotes 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

% colors
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color} % colors
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl} % more control over colors
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{122084}

% heading formats
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0.21in}{0.01in}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0.21in}{0in}


% table-related
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\bstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}} % space before row
\newcommand\astrut{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % space after row
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{-10.7cm}}
\titlespacing\section{6.67in}{0in}{0in}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont\bfseries}{\color{c1}}{20pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\color{c1}\vrule width 3pt}>{\hsp}r}#1\end{tabular}}

\section*{An Internationally \\ Renowned Title}

\vspace{0.5in}

\renewcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titlespacing\section{0cm}{0in}{0in}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont\bfseries}{\color{c1}}{20pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\color{c1}\vrule width 3pt}>{\hsp}l}#1\end{tabular}}

\section*{An Internationally \\ Renowned Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the title aligned at the right margin, must the vertical rule be on the left, or on the  right (i.e. the rule at the right margin)?

Comment: At the right please (as shown).

Comment: And do you have any numbered sections, possibly with a different layout?

Comment: None at all. Don't have to account for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was more efficient to use the relevant tool among the alignment tools provided by the package (`\filleft, \filright` and `filcenter`). I took the opportunity to simplify a bit your code – needless to load `color` if you load `xcolor` and loading the latter with option `[table]` will spare you having to load `colortbl` (in this case, load `tcolorbox` afterwards, to avoid an option clash).

```
% these define the type of document and the look of the page
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, top=1.3in, headheight=0.6in, showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage[bottom, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip} % space between footnotes
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

% colors
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % more control over colors
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{122084}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% heading formats
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0.21in}{0.01in}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0.21in}{0in}


% table-related
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\bstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}} % space before row
\newcommand\astrut{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % space after row
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titlespacing\section{0in}{0in}{0in}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont\bfseries\filleft}{}{0pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{\hsp\color{c1}\vrule width 3pt}}#1\end{tabular}}

\section*{An Internationally \\ Renowned Title}

\vspace{0.5in}

\titlespacing\section{0cm}{0in}{0in}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\color{c1}\vrule width 3pt\hsp}l}#1\end{tabular}}

\section*{An Internationally \\ Renowned Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Learned a lot more than I'd asked for from this - many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a pleasure to help!

Comment: I don't suppose you know why there are two vertical rules on the right-hand side when you load `showframe` with geometry?

Comment: You're referring to the thin line at the margins? `showframe is done for that: make visible the layout of the page. For  production, of course, remove this option.

Comment: Oh, apologies - I did know that. I meant - why are there two lines on the right as opposed to one only on the left?

Comment: But I don't have two (thick) lines! How do you get them? Or do I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107824/discussion-between-thevesh-theva-and-bernard).